# How would I access individual elements of this pandas dataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How would I access the individual elements of the dataFrame below?

More specifically, how would I retrieve/extract the **string** "CN112396173" in the index 2 of the dataFrame?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: by extract you mean just print that specific row? like this ```df.iloc[2,:]```?

Comment: I mean retrieve just the string CN11...  of each element. If I do as you say, it appears that I retrieve an object not a string as I intend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more accurate description of your problem would be: "Getting all first words of string column in pandas"

You can use `data["PN"].str.split(expand=True)[0]`. See [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html).

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"column": ["asdf abc cdf"]})
>>> series = df["column"].str.split(expand=True)[0]
>>> series
0    asdf
Name: 0, dtype: object
>>> series.to_list()
["asdf"]
```

`dtype: object` is actually normal (in pandas, strings are 'objects').